# counter example $\frac{G}{G^{n}}$ isomorphic with $G_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let's say that $G,.$ is a commutative group. We define:
$G_{n}$={$g \in G| g^{n} =e$} and $G^{n}$={$g^{n}|g \in G$}.

First I prove that $\frac{G}{G_{n}}$ is isomorphic with $G^{n}$.
Let's define a map $\phi: G\mapsto G^{n}$:$g \mapsto g^{n}$.
I prove that this is a morphism. Take $x,y\in G$ random  then  $\phi(x.y)$=$(x.y)^{n}$=$x^{n}.y^{n}$=$\phi(x).\phi(y)$ so $\phi$ is a morphism.
Now  I know that $ker(\phi)$={$f\in G|\phi(f)=e$}={$f\in G| f^{n}=e$}=$G_{n}$

So now it follows that $\phi'$:$\frac{G}{ker(\phi)} \mapsto G^{n}$:$gG_{n}\mapsto \phi(g)$ is an injective group morphism. So I proved it.

But now I'm stuck because I'm looking for an counter example that $\frac{G}{G^{n}}$ isn't isomorphic to $G_{n}$. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Name an infinite commutative group.

Comment: Looks like your proof is correct. Maybe there's something wrong with the problem?

Comment: No i'm trying to give a counterexample so that $G/G^{n}$ isn't isomprphic with $G_{n}$

Comment: I'm really sorry I didn't saw you're comment David. I maybe thougt $Z_{4}$X$Z_{4}$ but that's not infinite?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is false is true for finite groups. So you definitely need an infinite group.

Comment: @mathmath Can you find a counterexample with $(\mathbb Z, +)$ ?

Comment: But that's a group with +?

Comment: @mathmath "+" is just a symbol. We could use anything else. Or you can define a new "multiplication" $*$ on $\mathbb Z$ so that $x*y=:x+y$. In fact, it is quite common, for Abelian groups, to use symbols resembling addition (as opposed to multiplication).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm not thinking of anything directly

Comment: I thougt ($\mathbb{R},+$) is a infinite commutative group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $G=\mathbb Z, +$ and $n=3$. Then $G_3=\{0\}$ and $G^3= 3\mathbb Z$, but $G/G^3=\mathbb Z_3$.